# PHP Memory Warning—Upload Form

Tags: php, forms, modx

I'm working on creating a photo upload form and I'm running into some trouble. Essentially, a user fills out some basic demographic data, checks a media release, selects a photo, and uploads it. I then use a few nested `if` statements to validate that it's the correct photo size, type, etc.

At times it works just fine, but with certain photos I've been getting this error:

> PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 11310075 bytes exceeds the limit
>   of 8388608 bytes

Followed by a bunch of

> PHP: Notice: Undefined Index

for each of elements  in my `$_POST` array. I did some digging with `phpinfo()` and found that memory_limit is set to 128M...so I'm confused as to what's going wrong.

I'm using MODX, Apache/2.2.25

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not about memory, but max upload/post data limit. Please check you phpinfo() for:

> post_max_size
>
> upload_max_filesize

These values should be increased. This can be done by editing php.ini file, or by set_ini() function.

Comment: ... and since `8388608 bytes = 8 MB` odds are someone's trying to upload a file larger than 8 MB (which they are - looks like about 10.8 MB).

Answer (score 0):

You can set unlimited memory usage with this code.
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');